# 555 Circuit for Spark Gap Lighter Not Functioning Correctly

Tags: mosfet, oscillator, 555, spark

I have a circuit designed and fabricated with the following schematic:

[image: 555 Timer and MOSFET spark gap circuit.]

The specific 555 timer I'm using is a NE555DR.

However, when under power the circuit doesn't appear to oscillate and no spark appears at the other side of my transformer. If anyone has any quick pointers why, it'd be much appreciated!

Working voltage is 3.7V from a LiPo. When I probe the OUT pin of the oscillator, I just see ~1.5V stable.

Comment: What are you using for probing? A multimeter will show some random value near the average, so you could not rule out that it is oscillating.

Comment: I was using a multimeter with frequency detection, just looking for non-zero hz. DC power showed 1.45V.

Comment: your R5 is chosen too large, I'd say. This will just eat power.

Comment: U2 is not a voltage stabilizer. All it can do is regulate down.

Comment: Your MOSFET has a threshold voltage that is too high to be switched on with 3.7 V. You need to pick a different MOSFET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NE555 needs more than 4.5V of supply voltage; you're feeding it with less.

You have two options:

1. (not recommended) replace your step-down converter with a step-up converter producing at least 5.0V and continue to use the obsolete NE555.
2. (better) replace your NE555 with a CMOS-based 555 (LMC555, or **many** others); these work with far lower supply voltages. This has the added advantage of only requiring a tiny fraction of the really quite high supply current of the NE555 and instantly significantly improving battery life. You don't need the step-down converter.
3. (recommended) simply use a simpler oscillator circuit than the 555. Your spark gap doesn't need high frequency accuracy, so a simple relaxation oscillator made of a comparator, three resistors and a capacitor would do. Alternatively, a Pierce oscillator made from a CMOS inverter, a capacitor and a quartz crystal would be very stable (much more stable than any 555 circuit!), but the cheapest quartz crystals on the market would probably have a 32.768 Hz, not 21.818 Hz.

Note that your schematic specifies 6 significant digits for the frequency of your NE555 oscillator, but that's a lie if one reads it literally: six significant digits would mean the oscillator achieves an accuracy of better than 1 ppm; that's impossible with a 555 and a 100 nF capacitor. You'd be very happy if you achieve 3 % accuracy. low-frequency crystal oscillators however routinely achieve 3 ppm accuracy, thus being 10,000 times more accurate.

Comment: Thank you! Such a simple oversight, but I believe you're correct. I will remake the circuit with LMC555 or similar as you suggested.

Comment: @CharlesDeanModrich if you go for that, throw out the step-down converter; it does you no good!

Comment: Thanks again for your recommendations! FYI the Oscillator's exact frequency isn't important, I just need it to get into the ~20kHz range for my spark gap circuit transformer to work properly, doesn't have to be stable or accurate really. 

The buck is actually to control another part of the circuit so I still need it for my application, but wanted to include it here for context. Thanks again for the input!

Comment: Do you have any other schematics that you could point to that would do what I'm trying to do to drive the mosfet/coil but with a simpler oscillator?

Comment: @CharlesDeanModrich https://www.ti.com/lit/an/szza043/szza043.pdf page 13 , figure 19 (Pierce oscillator). simply buy a dual (or more) gate inverter IC, and use the second inverter as "buffer" for the oscillation. You'd connect the input of the second inverter to the output of the inverter in Figure 19, and connect the output of the second inverter to the MOSFET gate. Many crystals would work, basically anything cheap from https://www.digikey.de/short/9cwmm3jd would do.

Comment: @CharlesDeanModrich but even simpler, if you buy an inverter IC with 3 or more inverter gates, you can also build a very simple ring oscillator; inverter A -> RC filter -> inverter B -> inverter C -> input of inverter A. Anything from https://www.digikey.de/short/wz2hd7bm would do. Both options, this RC-slowed down ring oscillator and the Pierce oscillator above, are pretty resilient against supply voltage variations, so that if you use an inverter with sufficiently large input voltage range, you don't need any voltage regulation, so you can save yourself the hassle of U2 altogether.

Comment: (as described in the answer, the RC-based oscillator would be simple and inaccurate in frequency, and the Pierce oscillator would be very accurate. It depends on what you want.)

Comment: note that your MOSFET choice is infeasible, your voltage regulator was the wrong choice if you really want "voltage stabilization" as your title suggests, and your choice of 555 was wrong: I think it's time for a new board.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152133/discussion-between-charles-dean-modrich-and-marcus-muller).

Comment: If you have any more comments on why the MOSFET choice is not good, or if you have alternatives I'd very much appreciate it

Comment: explained what's wrong with the MOSFET in my comment under your question!

Comment: Ah, thank you!!